# Using jQuery DataTables with Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I need some advice regarding the usage of jQuery DataTables with Aurelia.  Basically I'm running into two problems.

1. I can't determine the best way to initialize it AFTER the `repeat.for` binding loop has completed. Apparently that loop is still working even after the `attached()` lifecycle is fired.
2. If I use `$(myRef).DataTables(data: myArray)` method to populate the table, and insert links (`<a href-route=... click.delegate=...>`) into that table, Aurelia doesn't seem to recognize the links or activate the router.

**Problem 1:** Here's my attempt to populate the table using **Aurelia's binding**.  Aurelia correctly makes the table, and I can just wait 2-3 seconds and then load DataTables, but that's not the right way.  I don't have a definitive event to trigger the loading of the DataTables class because I don't know when repeat.for is completed.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table ref="tblUserList" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><span t="Username"></span></th>
        <th><span t="First_name"></span></th>
        <th><span t="Last_name"></span></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr repeat.for="record of records">
        <td><a route-href="route: user; params.bind: {id: record.user_id}" click.delegate="$parent.select(record)">${record.user_username}</a></td>
        <td>${record.p_fname}</td>
        <td>${record.p_lname}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Problem 2:** Here's my attempt to populate the table using the **jQuery method**.  DataTables successfully loads the table, but Aurelia doesn't recognize the links or trigger action.

```
$(this.tblUserList).dataTable({
  "paginate": true,
  "pageLength": 10,
  data: this.records,
  columns: [
    { data: 'user_username',
      fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
        $(nTd).html("<a route-href='route: user; params.bind: {id:" + oData.user_id + "}' click.delegate='$parent.select(" + oData.user_id + ")'>" + oData.user_username + "</a>");
      }
    },
    { data: 'p_fname' },
    { data: 'p_lname' }
  ]
});
```

Can anyone help me solve any one of the above problems?  Or... am I approaching this whole issue the wrong way?  Is it better to use the jQuery method to populate, or the Aurelia `repeat.for` binding loop?

Comment: One of your problems may possibly be that the `repeat.for` loop is never _actually_ completed. It's bound to your `records` variable and so will update whenever that updates. I'm a bit confused as to where your issue lies though. Is Aurelia creating your table correctly, but jQuery never init's `dataTable()` on it?

Comment: Aurelia creates the table correctly, and if I add `window.setInterval(initTable(), 2000)` to add a 2-second delay, it inits correctly.

Comment: Hi, maybe you can try to load data with ajax https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html. Later i will look at your example

Comment: I already have the data stored locally as a JavaScript array of objects.  It would be redundant to get it via ajax, plus it still wouldn't fix the fact that Aurelia's not recognizing the links and click events since they're added to the DOM dynamically via 3rd party.

Comment: I've got the same problem and the far as I could get was to the "compile" option used in angular. Somehow I believe that we need to trigger the binding of aurelia to "attach" these methods to the corresponding DOM elements. Unfortunately I still didn't figured out how... by now I'm setting a global click function to the datatable element and then I filter from where the click came.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is old, but just in case, if it can help.
When you add DOM elements after binding, they are not *aureliazed*.  You should use the enhance method of `TemplatingEngine`:

1. import the `TemplatingEngine` and inject it:

   ```
   import {inject, TemplatingEngine} from 'aurelia-framework';
   @inject(TemplatingEngine)
   ```
2. In the constructor, initialize the template engine:

   ```
   constructor(templatingEngine) {
       this.templatingEngine = templatingEngine;
   }
   ```
3. in Aurelia's `attached()` method, do your datatable init stuff, and add a class to be able to retrieve your newly created DOM elements:

   ```
   $(nTd).html("<a class='myclass' ...
   ```
4. Enhance your elements:

   ```
   $('.myclass').each(function (index, value) { 
     let el = $(this);
     if (!el.hasClass('au-target')) { //can't enhance already aureliazed elm
       this.templatingEngine.enhance({element: el[0], bindingContext: this});
       //el[0] is important to have DOM and not jQuery object
     }
   });
   ```

Then your binding should work.

Answer (score 1):

Using the first approach (aurelia binding), remove *data* from the config object and load your data in the *activate* lifecycle hook:

```
import 'datatables';

export class UserList {
    activate() {
        this.records = [...];
    }

    attached() {
        $(this.tblUserList).dataTable();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work because on attached the data is still being written out to the DOM and so DataTables gets an incomplete set of data.

Comment: could it be something else, I loaded 10000 records both sync and async without problems. https://github.com/arabsight/datatables-demo